# how to update field names automatically after updating SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am changing the command text for a data set inside the `.rdl` ffile:

[image]

I would like to know how can I update the resulting `fields` that are returned by the select statement:

[image]

I know that these fields must be automatically generated, so I was wondering if it's possible to update them right after editing the SQL code inline??

Comment: please dont answer all at once

Comment: Are you doing this in Business Intelligence Development Studio or in the raw xml in the RDL?  I believe you can get at the commandt ext directly with an expression if you need it later with: =DataSets!DataSetName.CommandText.  I would not try to hack at the RDL without an IDE as it would be painful at best to work with it.

Comment: @djangojazz thank you very much for the suggestion. would you say that i should almost always be using the IDE and not playing with the RDL? yes i am using BIDS

Comment: Oh yeah, definitely.  Let me post a more thorough response as an answer as some things I have seen for use of things changing.

Comment: @djangojazz thank you so much i am looking forward to it!

Comment: @djangojazz eagerly awaiting your response :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when someone wants to have a look at the data in command text they are wanting it for reference to an end user(from what I have seen).  You may want to amend it but ultimately with reporting your first goal should be: "What am I doing this for?"  If your goal is dynamic creation at runtime then I would avoid this and offer a few other suggestions:

1. Procertize it.  Making a stored procedure if you have the know how in SQL Server is a convenient and fast way to get what you want and you can optimize it if you know what you are doing with your SQL FU to get good results.  The downside would be if you work with multiple environments you have to deploy your code for the TSQL as well as the RDL file.
2. Use an expression to build the dataset at runtime.  In cases where I have been told that the query itself was not properly optimized by other developers they have mentioned doing this.  I myself do not always see the advantage of doing this versus just having your predicate construction work well with good indexing on the source engine.  Regardless you can build your dataset at runtime.  It would be similar to hitting 'fx' next to the text and then putting in something like this(assuming you have a variable named @Start):

   ```
   ="Select thing 
   from table 
   Where >= " & Parameters!Start.Value
   ```

   Again I have not really seen if this is really that much faster than:

   ```
   Select thing
   from table
   Where >= @Start
   ```

   But it is there if you just want to build it dynamically.
3. You can try to build your expression dynamically from parameters being PART of the select statement.  SSRS is all about the 'expressions' and what you can do with them.  Once you jump in and learn how they apply to everything you can go nuts so to speak on using them.  A general rule though is the more of them you use and rely on the slower your reports will become.

I hope some of this may help, I would ask first is something dynamic due to a need to be event driven or is performance related.